# Concat multi-dimensional array into one-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with objects

```
const nodes = [ { children: [1, 2, 3] }, { children: [1, 2, 3] } ];
```

I want a new array `[ 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 ]`.

I have tried

```
nodes.map(node => node.children);
```

but it gives me `[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]`.

I have tried

```
[].concat(nodes.map(node => node.children));
```

but it doesn't work since it is just concatenating `[]` with `[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]` which is just `[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const nodes = [ { children: [1, 2, 3] }, { children: [1, 2, 3] } ],
      result = nodes.reduce((r, node) => r.concat(node.children), []);

console.log(result);
console.log([... new Set(result)]); // for unique values
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! After reducing, I am removing duplicates with `.filter((item, pos, self) => self.indexOf(item) == pos)`. Does it make sense to do this inside the `reduce` instead of afterwards with chaining?

Comment: you could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for unique values.

Comment: is it the same as `Array.from(new Set(result))`?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const nodes = [ { children: [1, 2, 3] }, { children: [1, 2, 3] } ];

var result = nodes.reduce(function(r, o) {
  r = r.concat(o.children);
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this using [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
const nodes = [ { children: [1, 2, 3] }, { children: [1, 2, 3] } ]
final = []
nodes.forEach(x => final = final.concat(x.children))
console.log(final)
```

Another shorter way is (a little modification to what OP was trying to do):

```js
const nodes = [ { children: [1, 2, 3] }, { children: [1, 2, 3] } ];
var result = [].concat.apply([], nodes.map(x => x.children))
console.log(result);
```